# How do you do a function in terms of the Y axis instead of the X axis with Sympy in Python?

Tags: python, function, sympy

I´m trying to code a Game Theory method to find optimal mixed strategies of a game of 2x2 order.

Anyway, to do that I require to define two functions, one which is in terms of the x axis and another which is in terms of the y axis (yes, the classic axes required to work in the two dimensional plane), so later a can obtain the intersection points.

For example;
suppose I have the next functions obtained from the 2x2 game:

L(y)= y+1

L(x)= x-2

where:

```
   if L(y)> 0, i.e., y+1>0, then x=1 (this is if y>-1 then x=1)
   if L(y)< 0, then x=0  (this is if y<-1 then x=0)
   if L(y)= 0, then x∈[0,1] (this is if y=-1 then x∈[0,1])
```

and

```
   if L(x) >0 then  y=1 (this is: if x>2 then y=1)
   if L(x) <0 then  y=0 (this is: if x<2 then y=0)
   if L(x) =0 then  y∈[0,1] (this is: if x=2 then y∈[0,1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCHr4.jpg

I was searching for a Python library that could do this, and I found that with sympy one can create piecewise functions like what I´m trying to do. I was doing something like this:

```
    from sympy import symbols, Piecewise
    x,y = symbols('x,y')

    p = Piecewise((1, x > 2), (0, x <2))
    q = Piecewise((1, y>-1), (0,y<-1))
```

and then find the intersection points from it. The problem is that Python doesn't care about the "name" of the variable and it treats them both as if they where in the same X axis.

Also I have trouble plotting them both at the same time and of course finding the intersection point in it. Is that even possible for Python?
What should I do, or what other way I could approach this problem.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "intersection of p and q" that you want to know the conditions for when they are the same, you can "fold" Tuple(p, q) to show you:

```
>>> piecewise_fold(Tuple(p, q))
Piecewise(
  ((1, 1), (x > 2) & (y > -1)),
  ((1, 0), x > 2),
  ((0, 1), y > -1),
  ((0, 0), True))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to apply a linear transformation to a picewise function, like, for example, a reflection through the x=y lines?

Comment: In theory, yes. If you use Point instead of Tuple in the above, the Piecewise will contain Points and `Point(p,q).reflect(Line(x-y))` will reflect (p,q) across the line `y=x`.